# Custom rule added to the HTML mode that uses "push" instead of "next" doesn't work

Tags: ace-editor

I want to customize the HTML mode so I can edit LIT-html template strings with it. I did add a rule  to `start` that matches `${`, switching the state to `js-start`. This works when I add `next: 'js-start'` to the rule. However, as the JavaScript code can include nested HTML (wrapped in `` lit.html`...` `` ), I would have to use `push` instead of `next`, but then the rule does not seem to work any more.

As a follow-up, as `${` can occur anywhere, I assume I will have to copy my new rule to any state defined for HTML, right? (i.e. all states on `this.$highlightRules.$rules` that do not start with `js-` or `css-`).

Code Snippet:

```js
const editor   = ace.edit(wrap);
const HtmlMode = ace.require("ace/mode/html").Mode;

const CustomMode = function() {
    HtmlMode.call(this);
    
    const HtmlHighlightRules = ace.require("ace/mode/html_highlight_rules").HtmlHighlightRules;
    this.$highlightRules     = new HtmlHighlightRules();
    
    this.$highlightRules.$rules.start.unshift({
        token: "punctuation.definition.tag",
        regex: /\${/,
        
        // works
        next: 'js-start',
        
        // does not work
        //push: 'js-start',
    });
};

CustomMode.prototype = Object.create(HtmlMode.prototype);
CustomMode.prototype.constructor = CustomMode;
CustomMode.prototype.$id = "ace/mode/lit-html";

editor.getSession().setMode(new CustomMode());
```

As expected, something like `<p class="something">${Math.random()}</p>` is correctly higlighted. But as soon as I use `push` instead of `next`, `Math.random()` is *not* highlighted, i.e. ACE does not switch to `js-start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to call

```
this.$highlightRules.normalizeRules()
```

after adding rules that `push`/`pop` - these are [a shorthand](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/64101ccf7e60d8f5bab26ca0108111a6f4690db2/src/mode/text_highlight_rules.js#L156-L164) for supplying functions that manipulate the state "stack".